# Site-wide "close" stats incorrect

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, review-stats

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) it claims I've only closed 11 questions.  That number is *way* off - I've probably actually closed 10x that.

Comment: But that's on StackOverflow, yes?  So wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask on their Meta?

Comment: @Ollie: Presumably this is a bug with the stackexchange software, which is why I posted it here

Comment: @Ollie the list showing only the top reviewers, even with 11k reviews OP won't be there.

Comment: You have [352 reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238419/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1) and the last close review you did was in 2016. You might have closed more questions outside of the queue but for reviews I expect that number of 11 reviews to be spot on. Can you do one actual close review in the queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page you linked to is showing statistics for **review** actions.

When you vote to close a question directly (not via a review), it's not a review action and it won't count in the Review Stats page.

To see your actual reviews, you can visit the [reviews tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238419/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity&sort=reviews) in your user profile on the site.

Comment: @Ollie those are review actions, which are public. The "votes" tab that hold direct close votes is indeed "private" and can be accessed only by the user or diamonds.

Comment: I find it strange that those actions would be considered distinct, but that does explain it.  Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRaja yeah sometimes SO/SE is weird like that.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Shadow Wizard's answer, you can view a list of *all* the votes for closure you've cast by navigating to https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure.

You have over 10k reputation and, thus, have the ability to see deleted posts, so this will list all votes for closure you've cast over the course of your time on Stack Overflow. This should give you a better idea of how many questions you've helped close. This includes votes you've cast while in the Close Votes queue and those you've cast while operating outside of it. Users who do not have 10k reputation will not see questions they voted to close that have since been deleted.